# sort string from the third character in java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

How can I sort the `String` from the third character ?

I know I can use bubble sorting, but it is a lot of work and there is a java `Comparator` class that can be used to compare two objects. I can compare it based on the first character, but I would like to sort it from the third character.

This is my code to compare and sort two strings:

```
public class test implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

How can I modify it to sort from the third character, not from the first ?

**Edit:** My code only execute the comparator part when the `String` length is greater or equals to 3 so there is no way that string size will be less than 3 characters.

Comment: what if string is empty or just has 1 or 2 characters?

Comment: no the string size is 3 or greater.

Comment: my string is always greater then 3 characters that is the situation.

Comment: Ok then the answer below by sufiyan should work.

Comment: Can you tell us more about "*I want to sort it from the third character*"? Should `"abcc"`, `"dbca"` be swapped or not (3rd chars are same, 4th chars are not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return `substring` instead of the actual `String`,

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
     return s1.substring(2).compareTo(s2.substring(2));
}
```

Comment: it will not work for empty string or with less than 3 characters.

Comment: Yes, but the `String` length is always more than 3 characters as per the OP comment.

Comment: It will be rather slow though, because it creates new strings all the time.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse   but it cannot be done any other way, right ? if it can then please suggest.

Comment: You can write a comparator based on e. g. `charAt`, and maybe there is a `compare` somewhere that allows specifying an offset. Also, you could sort pairs, where the key is the substring (computed once only) or use a hashmap to cache substrings (easy, but probably the second slowest to repeated substrings)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.substring` in your comparetor, so you can write something like:

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() > 2 && s2.length() > 2) {
        return s1.substring(2).compareTo(s2.substring(2));
    } else if (s1.length() > 2) {
        return 1;
    } else if (s2.length() > 2) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        // What you are supposed to do
    }
}
```

### Edit:

As you are sure that strings given to this method, all have more than or equal to 3 characters, so you can write only the necessary part:

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.substring(2).compareTo(s2.substring(2));
}
```

Comment: actually this is not needed because i am already performing the sorting part only when the string length is greater or equal to 3 character so the else/if block of your code would never be reached.

Comment: I didn't know it, so it's OK to remove the other parts than content of if.

Comment: but this is the same answer as the other one..isnt it against rules of StackOverFlow?

Comment: At the first edit, it was not same at all! But now, it looks like the other one, with some extra consideration codes.

Answer (score 1):

The `substring()` based approach has been mentioned before. However, for any two comparisons, it will *copy* your string into a new array - this is farily expensive (it has become even more expensive in Java 7 - in Java 6, substring would avoid copying the data).

If you want a faster solution, it's not hard to write a comparator yourself.

```
public class SubstringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    int first = 2;
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        final int l = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length());
        for (int i = first; i < l; i++) {
            int c = Integer.compare(s1.charAt(i), s2.charAt(i));
            if (c != 0) return c;
        }
        return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
    }
}
```

This approach is also safe if you have strings shorter than 3 characters.